# Message box in CATScript

Tags: vbscript, catia

i need to create a message box in CATScript / VBscript and it should have two buttons with names " Next " and "Before " or i could use ">|" and " |< " . How do i create a custom Msgbox . This is the code i am trying to execute according to it .

P.s : What do i replace in the position of VbYesNo in the example

```
result = Msgbox ( " Crank Position " , vbYesNo , "blah blah)
Select case result 
Case vbYes 
crankangle++
Case VbNo 
crankangle--
End Select
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot edit the text on the buttons of a messagebox..
You can create your own MessageBox using another Windows Form.

Be aware a messagebox is just a form, which is predefined in the Windows OS.
A form which is showed with showdialog does exactly the same.

I hope this awnsers your question!

P.S. 
Look at this forum: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/fdb0097b-4414-480f-b941-7f62017d2e92/change-msgbox-button-text

If you scroll down to the third reply you see an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hta application (in case you don't want to use vba or vb.net), with whole code for running in CATIA inside of hta and your custom buttons also inside hta.

Answer (score 0):

If you have C++ knowledge, and more time to work on that, you can use [CAA](http://www.3ds.com/partners/partnership-programs/software-partners/resources-services/developer-training/caa-v5-for-catia-getting-started/) to create advanced forms. It's a version of C++ adapted to Catia. It requires a license to be used.